# how to upload my xml which is created in jquery to php array

Tags: php, jquery, xml

Hello i am trying to figure this out. I am super new to php and passing method of array to array php. In this code its doing every time i do something it created that xml with values. What i am trying to do it sent this to php array for later use of database. And i cant figure it out somehow.Thank you

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);

var forcount=0;
var xmlarray= [], xmlcount=0;

function createxmlstruc (){

function xmlstruc() {
    var node = doc.createElement(arguments[0]), text;

for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if(typeof arguments[i] == 'string') {
        node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(arguments[i]));
    }
    else {
        node.appendChild(arguments[i]);
    }
}
return node;
};




var root = xmlstruc('Row',
    xmlstruc('TestNum', '' +rownumbarr[forcount]),
    xmlstruc('D_VALUE','' +DVALUE[forcount]),
    xmlstruc('I_VALUE','' +IVALUE[forcount]),
    xmlstruc('S_VALUE','' +SVALUE[forcount]),
    xmlstruc('C_VALUE','' +CVALUE[forcount]),
    )
xmlstruc();
console.log(root);
xmlarray[xmlcount++] = root; // in here adding xml's 1 by 1
xmlreturn(xmlarray);
forcount+=1;    
}

var resulta=0;

function xmlreturn (backtoxml) {
    if(resulta == 48){
    $("#resultbutton").trigger('click');
    }
    return backtoxml;
}
```

i put to array whenever xml created and trying to do something with it. Is it right?
and there is no answers like what i seek or solution like

and xml created like this

```
<Row>
<RowNum>1</RowNum>
<D_VALUE>1</D_VALUE>
<I_VALUE>3</I_VALUE>
<S_VALUE>4</S_VALUE>
<C_VALUE>2</C_VALUE>
```

```
<Row>
    <RowNum> 2</RowNum>
    <D_VALUE>4</D_VALUE>
    <I_VALUE>1</I_VALUE>
    <S_VALUE>3</S_VALUE>
    <C_VALUE>2</C_VALUE>
</Row>
```

ok i looked again for test for using this

```
<?php
// function defination to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_numeric($key) ){
            $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
        }
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
     }
}

// initializing or creating array
$data = array($xmlarray);

// creating object of SimpleXMLElement
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');
// function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($data,$xml_data);

//saving generated xml file; 
$result = $xml_data->asXML('Z:\downloads\name.xml');

?>
```

How to use array which contain xml's in this function which is create a xml file ?
And php says undefined $xmlarray ofcourse i dont know how to use it kappa :{

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

Comment: @LinusJuhlin thnx i will give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am used this. I put those xml into string variable and send it to php string thats how i solved this.